# How to display shimmer while connecting to api or fetching data using StreamProvider<T>.value()

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this simple widget. I would like to have a shimmer while client still fetching or connecting to api.

It's the condition I am struggling with. I have created the shimmer widget already. And after client already done fetching/connecting, would like to display a text for client to add new hero if no heroes were found such as shown below.

```
class HeroesHomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<List<Hero>>.value(
          value: //...db_fetch_here...
        ),
        //...other providers
      ],
      child: HeroesScreen()
    )
  }
}
```

```
class HeroesScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final heroes = Provider.of<List<Hero>>(context, listen: false) ?? [];

    if(heroes.length <= 0) return Text('No heroes yet. Tap here to add');

    // Not sure where or what condition should I write 
    // to show shimmer while client still fetching data
    // or client still connecting to api

    return SomeWidget();
  }
}
```

```
class Hero {
  String id;
  String name;
}
```

Comment: Can you also share your `Hero` class

Comment: @SelimKundakçıoğlu I have added the hero class. It's a simple class only.

Comment: Why can't you just show the Shimmer while waiting for the data and switch to the list of heroes once the data has loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi as per the documentation it undesired to use the `StreamProvider.Value` to pass a value. Especially when the value is prone to change. Check the docs [here](https://pub.dev/packages/provider#usage). You can provide an initial value and then handle it as shown below.

```dart
class HeroesHomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  Stream<List<Hero>> getHeroes(BuildContext context) async* {
    //do a db fetch here
    List<Hero> heroes = [
      Hero()
        ..id = '1'
        ..name = 'IronMan',
      Hero()
        ..id = '2'
        ..name = 'CaptainAmerica',
    ];
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5)); // simulate a delay.

    yield heroes;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<List<Hero>>(
          create: getHeroes,
          initialData: null,
        ),
        //...other providers
      ],
      child: HeroesScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Instead you can check the data being passed to the consumer widget like shown below and decide what to render. Here I am checking if the list is null and displaying a circular progress indicator.

```dart
class HeroesScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Consumer<List<Hero>>(
        builder: (context, List<Hero> heroes, child) {
          if (heroes == null)
            // replace the return with your shimmer widget
            return Card(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: heroes.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                child: Text('My hero is hero ${heroes[index].name}'),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Appreciate it. So inside Consumer widget, I can check if heroes is empty then display some sort of `Text('tap here to add new hero')`, right?

Comment: Yes. If you want to directly work with the stream then perhaps `StreamBuilder` should be used where you can check if `snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.Waiting` then display some shimmer else display your widget as described in the documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html).

Comment: Perfect! I think this is what im looking for. Thank you so much!